# hashi_vault pass variable/argument into the lookup query

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

Do you know if I'm able to pass variable into the lookup query?

```
password: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my_secret:data')['{{ myvar }}']}}"
```

where myvar is set to mypass

```
vault kv put secret/my_secret mypass=abcd123
```

I'm getting the following error.

> {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{myvar}}'\n\nThe error appears to be in '.../ansible/roles/joetests/tasks/main.yml': line 23, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n - debug:\n ^ here\n"}

I've tried different quotations but it doesn't seem to work

```
password: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my_secret:data')['"{{ myvar }}"']}}"
password: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my_secret:data')["'{{ myvar }}'"]}}"
```

If I use the following it returns the password successfully.

```
password: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my_secret:data')['mypass']}}"
```

I'm currently testing a very simple playbook

```
---
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ item }} => {{ password }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ myvar }}"
```

where

```
myvar:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every variable inside the curly braces (`{{ }}`) will be interpolated, so the trick here is to actually remove the quotes altogether. Try this instead:

```
password: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my_secret:data')[myvar] }}"
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt, this did the trick.  I thought I'll need some sort of quotes as if I'm reading the single vault secret, the syntax is ['mypass']